# getScript stopped working

Tags: jquery, getscript

To speed up the load time of our site, we defer the loading of some scripts. This has been working fine until a couple of days ago. I've boiled the issue down to this short page of HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                var scriptUrl = "http://ads.trafficspaces.net/v1.22/adservice.js";
                jQuery
                    .getScript(
                        scriptUrl, 
                        function () {
                            alert("I'm never called")
                        });
            //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

It would appear that the script in question is served with a `text/plain` content type. I'm not sure what it was before the weekend. Could this be the problem?

Looking in Fiddler, it appears the request is never made, but I can fetch it when I paste the URL into another tab. If I change `scriptUrl` to one under my control, it works fine. What's going on?

Comment: Works for me :) http://jsbin.com/olevi4

Comment: Lightbulb moment. AdBlockPro. Grrr.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Your confirmation that it worked instantly brought me to the right conclusion. I switched on ABP because I was working remotely and animated adverts over RDP make it unusable. Silly me. The upside is that it's brought a not too uncommon case that needs dealing with in a more robust way. Thanks again.

Comment: added a few things to check in an answer below...I guarantee someone finds this later and has the same eureka moment :)

Comment: Yep. I deleted the question, then undeleted because it's been a painful hour of feeling stupid. If this helps the next person who cleverly tries to develop advert functionality while using an ad blocker then I thought it should remain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your addons/extensions and such, make sure that the ad script itself isn't being blocked by some other filter(ad blocker extension, proxy filter, etc).

It works for me, [you can test it here](http://jsbin.com/olevi4) - I'm testing in chrome with no ad blocker.